# How to modify collection of enum value in Java

Tags: java, java-8

My Class

```
public class Student {

private String name;
private Collection<ClassEnum> classes;

//getters & setters

}
```

Below is `ClassEnum`

```
public enum ClassEnum {
ENGLISH("english")
MATHS("maths")
SCIENCE("science")

private final String value;

//Constructor & Getter
}
```

As a result of the implementation, Finally i would get `List` of `Student` Object. Then, i would like to do some modification i.e If `ClassEnum` contains MATHS then it should be changed to ENGLISH

How to achieve that by iterating `List` of `Student` Object and then get `Collection` of `ClassEnum` and then how to replace MATHS with ENGLISH ?

**Note:**
As holger pointed out, `Collection<ClassEnum>` can be Mutable `List<ClassEnum>`

Comment: Declaring a variable as type `Collection` means having least information about its actual capabilities. It’s not clear whether replacements (or modifications in general) are possible. You should use `List` or `Set` to decide for specific semantics. Further, `class` is not a valid variable name.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out variable issue. i have modified now. Also, If i change to List<ClassEnum> can we modify existing enum values somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Holger pointed out, it is hard to know what kind of collection of `ClassEnum`s you want to save. For my solution I just assume you are storing an ordered sequence of classes.

```
public class Student{

   private String name;
   private List<ClassEnum> classes;

   public Student(String name, List<ClassEnum> classes) {
       this.name = name;
       this.classes = classes;
   }

   public void replaceMathByEnglish() {
       this.classes = this.classes.stream()
               .map(subject -> subject == ClassEnum.MATHS ? ClassEnum.ENGLISH : subject)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
   }

   public List<ClassEnum> getClasses() {
       return this.classes;
   }

   public String getName() {
       return this.name;
   }
}

public enum ClassEnum {
    ENGLISH("english"),
    MATHS("maths"),
    SCIENCE("science");

    private final String value;
    
    public ClassEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Code to test the implementation:

```
Student max = new Student("Max", Arrays.asList(ClassEnum.ENGLISH, ClassEnum.MATHS));
Student fritz = new Student("Fritz", Arrays.asList(ClassEnum.MATHS, ClassEnum.MATHS, ClassEnum.SCIENCE));
List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(max, fritz);
    
students.forEach(student -> student.replaceMathByEnglish());
    
students.forEach(student -> System.out.println(student.getName() + ": " + student.getClasses()));
```

This will output:

```
Max: [ENGLISH, ENGLISH]
Fritz: [ENGLISH, ENGLISH, SCIENCE]
```

If you want to change arbitrary classes, it is quite simple to adjust the method in the Student class:

```
public void replaceClass(ClassEnum from, ClassEnum to) {
    this.classes = this.classes.stream()
            .map(subject -> subject == from ? to : subject)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: For a mutable `List`, you can also use `this.classes.replaceAll(subject -> subject == ClassEnum.MATHS ? ClassEnum.ENGLISH : subject);` to perform the change in-place.

Comment: Thanks Lucas Your Answer make sense! I will verify before i Approve